# Создание первого приложения MVC (Eclipse, Spring)

Tags: spring, mvc, eclipse

Не нашел ни одого толкового урока на просторах интернета.. литературы тоже очень мало.

помогите написать простейшее веб-приложение, используя Eclipse, MVC, Spring и мозги =)

заанее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Туториалов с hello world-ами в интернете (не в рунете) достаточно много. В еженедельной [рассылке от SpringSource](http://www.springsource.org/news-events/newsletters) постоянно мелькают новые и новые статьи о старом. Например:

- [Spring MVC 3.0 with STS Tutorial](http://duckranger.com/2011/07/spring-mvc-3-0-with-sts-tutorial-part-i/) (в трёх частях автор описывает и показывает как создать небольшое приложение с помощью Spring Tool Suite)
- [Spring 3 MVC hello world example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/) (не новая статья от известного блоггера описывающая как написать hello world на Spring 3.0; на сайте, кстати, есть ещё очень много подобных статеек с примерами)
- [Getting Started with Spring MVC](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/) (статья из оффициального блога, тоже пошаговое описание как запустить проект с помощью Maven)

От себя пару советов, если позволите:

- Eclipse тут не причем, в нём вы лишь будете набирать код. Если хотите, то попробуйте [STS](http://www.springsource.org/sts) (это Eclipse + разные плагины для технологий от SpringSource, в т.ч. и Spring)
- вам будет сложно, если с английским плохо. Почти всё (более 97%) на английском. Из книг на русский переведена только одна, причем в этом году
- если хотите хорошо разобраться со Spring-ом, то советую прочитать reference с офф. сайта. Для начала можете прочитать только ту часть, в которой рассказывается про MVC. Затем перейти к базовой, где описывается IoC контейнер и работа с бинами

Если что -- задавайте вопросы. Удачи вам!

Comment: Полностью согласен! Но если так уж плохо с английским, то на русском примеров hello word-а тоже хватает...
Вот тебе и в eclips - http://habrahabr.ru/post/83860/
Или вот в idea - http://upsize.ru/spring-mvc-step-by-step-tutorial/